# SQL date_format() vs PHP date()

Tags: php, sql, performance, date, format

In SQL, I can format the date field using the following:

```
SELECT article_name, DATE_FORMAT( article_date, '%b %e, %Y' ) AS my_date FROM tblArticles
```

The same thing can be done in PHP using:

```
echo date('M j, Y', strtotime($row['article_date']));
```

And in my page, there would be around 50+ items. So, in PHP I would loop through the records, format the date and print them. The formatting done via PHP could be avoided if I use the `date_format()` within the query itself.

So, among these two approaches, which one would you prefer(regarding performance) ?
My pages are likely to get several hit and this app would be hosted in a shared hosting. So, I am concerned with performance at the moment. I just don't want to give more load to my server. :)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing everything in SQL will probably be faster than doing in PHP, however you should profile the code to figure out the exact situation. There are also probably better places for you to optimize since this isn't likely to be a performance bottleneck in your system. The best way to determine where to focus your optimizing attention is to profile your code. Otherwise, you risk optimizing things that don't really make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to benchmark it and would try to find out.

Comment: +1 for the note about unneeded optimization - this probably isn't something the OP needs to be concerned with.

Comment: One strtotime() itteration takes aroun 4-4.5 milliseconds. Not an issue, unless the rest of the code executes in less time than that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing related to the performance in your question actually.

Please don't ask performance related questions just out of nowhere. Try to find whatever reason for them. 
Otherwise you may occupy yourself for years, with "important" questions like "what function to use?" "in what order to write operators" etc.

There is no difference in terms of performance. Such a silly data transformations will never affect it.
Large data processing should be your concern, not simple formatting functions.